# PyTorch DataLoader failed on "next" method

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I constructed a DataLoader and loaded a very sample dataset (10 samples, labels are 0 to 9)  to test the iterator. But the iterator seems to fail to proceed by next method. What's wrong with the code?

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, features, labels, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.labels = labels
        self.features = features

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = self.features[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return image, label
    
    
features = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
labels = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
dataset = CustomImageDataset(features, labels)
    
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2,
                        shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

for i in range(20):
    features, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
    print("=========")
    print('This is ' + str(i + 1) + "th time.")
    print(labels[0])
    print(labels[1])
```

The result:

```
=========
This is 1th time.
tensor(0)
tensor(1)
=========
This is 2th time.
tensor(0)
tensor(1)
=========
This is 3th time.
tensor(0)
tensor(1)
=========
This is 4th time.
tensor(0)
tensor(1)
=========
This is 5th time.
tensor(0)
tensor(1)
=========
This is 6th time.
tensor(0)
tensor(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new iteratble by `iter(dataloader)` in each pass of the `for` loop. You should create the `iterable` outside the `for` loop as follows:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, features, labels, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.labels = labels
        self.features = features

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = self.features[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return image, label
    
    
features = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
labels = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
dataset = CustomImageDataset(features, labels)
    
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2,
                        shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
iterable = iter(dataloader)
for i in range(20):
  try:
    features, labels = next(iterable)
    print("=========")
    print('This is ' + str(i + 1) + "th time.")
    print(labels[0])
    print(labels[1])  
  except StopIteration:
    print("iterable has been consumed")
    break
```